# Submitting app to app store which is not iPhone 5 screen compatible

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, iphone-5

I submitted an app which is not iPhone 5 screen compatible. I got a response from the App Store team as follows:

> Dear xxx,
>
> If you are updating your app for iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th
>   generation), you must provide additional screenshots to support the
>   new screen dimensions for the App Store. The new screenshot dimensions
>   are: 640 x 1136 (portrait) 640 x 1096 (portrait) 1136 x 640
>   (landscape) 1136 x 600 (landscape) To deliver new screenshots, go to
>   the Version Details page in the Manage Your Applications module on
>   iTunes Connect. If you deliver a new app binary that takes advantage
>   of the new screen size for iPhone 5 or iPod touch (5th generation)
>   without screenshots in the new dimensions, the status of your app will
>   change to Missing Screenshot. Your app will not be reviewed until you
>   upload screenshots with the correct dimensions. You will also need to
>   upload screenshots for any added localizations you have set up on
>   iTunes Connect. For more information on screenshot requirements, see
>   the Asset Specifications section in the iTunes Connect Developer
>   Guide. Regards, The App Store team

Since I am not targeting the app for iPhone 5, what are the steps that I should follow to resubmit it? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did your recently submitted app really get rejected? Please re-check its state, because I got the same email without even submitting a new version. It might be just a coincidence!

I think this is just a general note that Apple sent to all developers. Also, it says "**If** you are updating your app for iPhone 5...". So, if you are **not**, you can safely ignore the rest.

Comment: I got it too, without submitting an update. No worries.